# What are all the scriptural basis for Results of Karma?

Tags: karma

In other words, on what ‘basis’ the result for your actions are determined. I have seen very many references to how we should live our life so we accumulate Good Karma etc. in Vedic and non- Vedic sources like Sathyam Vadha, Dharmam Chara etc. I have also seen that we should not depend on the result of our actions and in fact offer that itself to Brahman in Gita.

However, I have not seen any direct reference on the basis of Karma phala determination in any source very clearly. There are some hints. I also know divisions of Karma (Sanchitha, Prarabda etc.) and what accumulates, what doesn’t, and what we bring into when we are born and what we carry forth when we leave etc. as well as Nitya Karma. But not very clear on how Karma phalam is determined.

Any scriptural references as to how this is determined would help. Without proper and clear definition, and grey areas, there are loopholes that entities could make use of for justifying immoral, unethical and overall incorrect actions correct?

Any proper scriptural references appreciated. **Older the better**.

My question is different from [Origin of Karma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/origin-of-the-law-of-karma) and such references from scriptures.

For e.g Who decides for e.g  "being high up in heaven, an eternity with Surya, eternal life, a long life, being invited first, becoming chief of your village, a horse, a bullock, gold, food, a bride, the light of heaven, the Universe"  AS RESULTS for your good karma of "giving Dakshina to the Brahmanas performing your Yagna". What is the Justification for such a result assignment and not something else?

More generally, What MUST be the Scriptural BASIS of such  RESULT assignment for Good OR Bad Karma? Whoever may be the decider.

How am I to find out if this is in Rig Veda that is not Tampered by Vyasa's Sishya for e.g? Where are the cross references? If you leave the result vague and ad-hoc instead of a Sound scriptural basis then the adoption of Good Karma is Vague too correct? That is the motivation behind this question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4YC5PTV7q4 Garbha Geeta discussion between Krishna-Arjuna on various kind of good-bad actions and their fruits, but its in Hindi,cant find english version.But eventual goal is Nishkama Karma Yoga or fruitless actions of Godhead. "Geeta 3.22 There is no duty for me to do in all the three worlds, O Parth, nor do I have anything to gain or attain.Yet, I am engaged in prescribed duties.As ignorant people perform their duties with attachment to the results,O scion of Bharat,so should the wise act without attachment, for the sake of leading people on the right path."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Origin of the Law of Karma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/origin-of-the-law-of-karma)

Comment: Unfortunately not...I have modified my question to be more clearer

Comment: Good question.  Formatted for increasing the readability.

Comment: you have asked too many questions under one 'question'. Many of the questions are duplicates of questions already answered. Need to focus your question down to one question. You might also want to do a search on this website for 'karma'.

Comment: Already searched for Karma. if the question What MUST be the Scriptural BASIS of such RESULT assignment for Good OR Bad Karma, Whoever may be the decider? is answered that is sufficient

Comment: I agree with @Swami Vishwananda . Besides the lack of focus , using caps in middle of sentences doesn't really help. If the question is how is accounting of Karma determined, then no text gives it. Gita explicitly states that accounting for karma runs deep

Comment: In Mahabharata their are many conversations where they mention action and their phal one-to-one. Will find references and publish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came about to research this myself, Here is the Answer.
**Yes. This is in the Rig V.**

> Rtam cha satyam chAbhithtAt (1), tapaso athyajAyata (2)
>
> > Truth was born and the Law of Truth (1), From the trigger fire of Energy of Consciousness.
> > Rig V. 10.190.1

> satyam brihat rtam ugram, thikshA tapo brahma yajnah, prithivi dhArayanti ||
>
> > The Truth (satyam), the Vast (brihat) and the Truth-in-movement (rtam), strength (ugram), initiation, askesis, mantra (brahma) and Yajna- These bolsters the Earth.
> > Atharva V 12.1.1

See a nice explanation [right here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26209/what-is-the-concept-of-ritam-as-per-the-vedas/26452)

Any Basis for Karma Result Assignment MUST be reliant on the axioms above.
That is Truth, Satyam plus Rtam

When you have something as Law, You automatically separate Sentience into the followers of a Law plus non-followers of a Law. The Result of their following or non-following of a Law Must be reliant on the ripple effect of their karma effect to the Law of Truth (Rtam) at the highest level i.e at the fire of Energy of Consciousness.

Comment: From the length of this answer I can tell you've made an effort at explaining yourself but frankly, speaking for myself, this went way over my head

Comment: @Vidyut time to see "if periodic coffee consumption elevates a person to understand truths that are required to be understood" :-)

Comment: good try, but a bit verbose for my taste. like einstein said "if you can't explain it to your grandma, you don't understand it". or like buddha said "the wise filter their thoughts before speaking". not every thought-stream needs to be written out , cos it distracts readers who have their own thought stream. This is not a Maths/Research paper :)

Comment: @ram Yes. Agree. It is not! The verbosity levels are as appropriate now!